# What is the Performance while fetching data from multiple tables using DISTINCT keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct

I'm curious to know how exactly does the sqldeveloper do the job when we query for data through multiple tables using DISTINCT keyword.

The reason I'm asking this is because I see it takes a lot of time for sqldeveloper to fetch me results when I use DISTINCT keyword

Comment: `EXPLAIN PLAN` for both queries: with and without DISTINCT

Comment: Also clarify how you're querying - if 'run statement' then only the first 50 rows (by default) are fetched into the data grid; adding `distinct` (or `order by` etc.) means more data needs to be processed before anything can be returned/displayed.

Comment: SqlDeveloper doesn't 'do the job'. It simply passes your query to the database to process. As you have a distinct it will only show results when the DB has processed the full results set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `select distinct`, the database needs to go through the effort of removing duplicate values.

In a minority of cases, all the columns/expressions in the `select` may be in an index.  If so, Oracle should be smart enough to use the index.  In this one case, the `select distinct` may not have a large impact on performance.

Otherwise, the database needs to aggregate the data.  The same algorithms are available for `select distinct` as for `group by`.  There are many of them, but they will definitely be slower than not using `select distinct`.

One other factor is that the database will not return *any* results until it has removed the duplicates from the result set.  In other cases, the database can start removing rows when they are available.

You should only use `select distinct` if you really need it, knowing that you will incur overhead for running the query.